# Why do we need custom route if we can define globally?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

If I can add routes in global.ascx or similar file then why do we need custom router i.e. the routes over individual WebApi methods. When it's needed? What is the benefit?

```
 [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
 [Route("api/AndroidOperations/AddManualAppointment")]
        public object AddManualAppointment(AddManualBookingViewModel AddManualBookingVM) 
        {
            BookingsRepository BookingRep= new BookingsRepository();

            int ReturnRowsCount = BookingRep.InsertManualCustomerAppointments(AddManualBookingVM, out ReturnStatus, out ReturnMessage, out ReturnBookingID);

            return new {ReturnMessage= ReturnMessage, ReturnStatus= ReturnStatus};
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Attribute Routing is a more flexible solution than Convention Routing, if only because it allows you quite a bit more flexibility and places the routes next to the actions that will actually use them.

Consider choosing traditional routes when:

- You want centralized configuration of all your routes.
- You use custom constraint objects.
- You have an existing working application you don’t want to change.

Consider choosing attribute routes when:

- You want to keep your routes together with your action’s code.
- You are creating a new application or making signifi cant changes to an existing one.

Attribute routing nicely keeps everything about your controllers together, including both the URLs they use and the actions that run. However there are certainly benefits to using both in tandem, particularly in situations when you know how some routes will look but aren't sure about others.

**Note:** Attribute Routing is more specific and overrides Convention Routing. Be sure attribute routing should be defined first to convention based routing.

To find out more see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#why-attribute-routing) and [Attribute Routing vs Convention Routing](https://exceptionnotfound.net/attribute-routing-vs-convention-routing/)

Comment: which overrides which one?

Comment: i.e. if i use both, one in global settigns and other is custom next to action then which one will be preferred by system.